# how to create thread on Map<k,v> that work all the time and remove key from the map?

Tags: java, multithreading, api, rest, hashmap

I'm writing REST API of coupons system,
and I'm trying to create a thread that works all the time that the server is running.

The thread needs to remove the token+client session if the client doesn't use the server (through the controllers class) passes 10 seconds.

The class of the thread:

```
public class ClientSessionCleaner implements Runnable {
private boolean run = true;

private Map<String, ClientSession> tokensMap;

public ClientSessionCleaner() {
    /*Empty*/
}

@Autowired
public ClientSessionCleaner(@Qualifier("tokens") Map<String, ClientSession> tokensMap) {
    this.tokensMap = tokensMap;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    HashMap<String, ClientSession> copy = new HashMap<>(tokensMap);
    do {
        CleanMap(copy);
    }while (run);
}

private void CleanMap(HashMap<String, ClientSession> copy) {
    copy.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - v.getLastAccessMillis() == 10 * 1_000){
            copy.remove(k);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm starting the thread in the main class, it is ok?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CouponSystemApplication.class, args);
    ClientSessionCleaner cleaner = new ClientSessionCleaner();
    Thread thread =new Thread(cleaner);
    thread.start();

}
```

When I'm starting the server I'm getting this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-178" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:496)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:485)
at com.Avinadav.couponsystem.rest.login.ClientSessionCleaner.run(ClientSessionCleaner.java:25)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The tokens map:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "tokens")
    public Map<String, ClientSession> tokensMap() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
```

}

I don't know if the thread code is ok (?) and what I should do to make the thread work.
I'm new with threads,
thx for all the help!

Comment: Is tokensMap really set?

Comment: You're calling the constructor of `ClientSessionCleaner` that does not set a `tokensMap` so of course its value is `null` when the `run` method is called. Supposedly `tokensMap` is created somewhere in the rest of your application - where?

Comment: Not sure if this is just omitted, but ClientSessionCleaner should be defined as a spring-bean.
Given it is defined as spring bean, you should obtain instance of it in main-method via spring instead of instantiating it directly, since otherwise dependencies will not be injected.

Comment: Your "...cleaner" thread, the way it's written now, is going to use 100% CPU, all the time. You should figure out a way to make it sleep until it's needed. If you wanted to get fancy, you probably could do the job with some `Timer`-like facility instead of using a dedicated thread, but even just putting a `sleep(500)` or a `sleep(100)` call in your top-level loop would give you substantial performance improvement.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but what good does it to to remove the tokens from a _copy_ of the `tokensMap`? Is that copy just a placeholder for something you're going to fill in later?

Comment: I add the tokens map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems like you're trying to implement some kind of a cleanup service for outdated `ClientSession`s. Is that right?

If so, your `Runnable` can actually be a `@Component` in which a `@Scheduled` annotation will define a periodic procedure in which the cleaning will take place.

For more info about Scheduling, check out the [The @Scheduled Annotation in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case *may* fit the functionality of a popular caching library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) or [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), because it has support for maps with [time-based eviction](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based) and it seems to be me that's what you're trying to accomplish.

```
LoadingCache<String, ClientSession> tokensMap = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

For more complex logic use `LoadingCache#expireAfter`. Using a library like this will prevent you from having to deal with complex concurrency issues.